# Is there any way to make a char array without knowing what size it will be

Tags: c++, c, arrays

```
char* a = new char[50];
```

This is for a school assignment. I am not allowed to use strings or vectors or anything else. Just char array.

Lets say I want to do `cin >> a;` and I don't know the size of the input. How should I put it in char array? The above only works for a small size of input.

Should I do this? `char* a = new char[some_large_number];` or is there a better way?

I can only use (dynamic) char arrays.

EDIT: The input can be any string like
`abcd` or even `somelongrandomsentecewithoutspsomelongrandomsentecewithoutspacessomelongrandomsentecewithoutspaces`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, he cannot use strings.

Comment: @JosuéMolina What a pity, they're required to implement this themselves :-P ...

Comment: First things first:  your school is teaching you *all the wrong things*.  Please feel free to share this observation with your professor, along with my lament that I have to retrain recent grads so extensively, and it's because teachers like your professor are teaching all the wrong things.

Comment: `cin.getline(a, 50);`

Comment: @JohnDibling: That depends on what the emphasis of the course is.  Intro to programming, you're right.  Anything related to compiler/library design, efficiency, data structures, understanding roughly how your libraries work is a very good thing.

Comment: @BenVoigt:  I presume OP is taking a first C++ course.

Comment: Do you have example input? If so, please add it to the post.

Comment: @JohnDibling: time to write a "Letter to the teachers" to be renamed into "char arrays considered harmful"....

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia: The `char` arrays aren't the problem.  The problem is spending a lot of time on concepts that are most needed during library design/implementation/debugging, and failing to teach proper modern use of existing libraries, which is applicable to every C++ programmer.  Again, there's nothing wrong with the former being part of the curriculum, but it's not the first thing you teach in an intro to programming course.

Comment: @BenVoigt: It seems you get the point o my irony. Thanks to the expansion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a little tricky with character arrays: what you need to do is tell `cin` that you do not want to receive more than a certain number of characters (49 for a 50-character buffer, because you need space for null terminator). When the read is finished, check the length of the string. If it is 49, allocate a new, larger, string, copy the old string into it, and continue reading. If it is less than 49, the end of string has been reached.

You can use [`istream::get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) to read the data into your buffer:

```
cin.get(a, 50); // You can specify an optional delimiter as a third parameter
```

Note that you pass 50 for the length, and `get` will subtract 1 automatically, because it knows about the space needed for null terminator.

Comment: Thank you. But wont that require copying the string multiple times.
What if I just initialize the initial array with a bigger size? Big enough like a 1000 if I know my input will always be less than 1000

Comment: @pizzaEatingGuy If you know there's a limit, you can definitely use a buffer of size 1000, then measure the exact length, allocate `length+1`, copy, and delete the temporary buffer.